# SVN Ignore all files (not the folders) in a subtree,

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/some_folder
/tmp
/tmp/foo
/tmp/foo/fu      *
/tmp/bar
/tmp/bar/bah     *
/tmp/bar/ba      *
/tmp/foobar      *
/more_folders
```

The `/tmp` directory is being used for caching and whatnot, so I want to have the *folder structure* under version control, but ignore all the *files* inside each directory.

Files will only exist in the leaf folders. That is, folders with no subfolders of their own: the starred ones in the above example.

Is my only option to set `ignore *.*` on each leaf, or is there a way to ignore all files (and just the files) in the entire `/tmp` subdirectory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you'll have to add the entire structure when its empty, then set ignore to * on each leaf.

I suppose that, if none of your tmp folders have dots in their names and all of your files do have dots, that setting an ignore at /tmp for `*.*` might work.

Comment: thanks for the tip! unfortunately, I just remembered that the files don't all have dots in them!

Comment: If you use Windows and TortoiseSvn, there is submenu to do that. http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested with Tortoise on Windows, added svn:ignore for * instead of *.* and it ignores now directories too :)

So the solution would be to add property svn:ignore * on /tmp

Comment: as for your question, maybe it will be better to have an install script create the folders